# Red5 Media Server - Error 1067 on Win 2008 Server x64

Tags: iis, red5

i'm trying to run the Red5 Media Server on my Live Server (Win Server 2008 R2).
installation worked, i've entered localhost with port 5080, but when trying to start the Red5 service i'm getting this error:

```
Windows could not start the Red5 service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

things i already tried (without success):

- run red5 setup as administrator
- run red5 service as administrator
- open port 5080 in firewall
- turn off iis before trying to start the service

any ideas what could be wrong? thanks

**UPDATE:**

i've checked the logs:
(i already set the JAVA_HOME user environment variable and rebooted) .. no success yet

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:42 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:42 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.3.6
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:42 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2009 Tanuki Software, Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:42 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:42 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Launching a JVM...
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 |     "java" -Xrs -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dlogback.ContextSelector=org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector -Dcatalina.useNaming=true -Dpython.home=lib -Xverify:none -Xms256m -Xmx768m -Djava.library.path="lib" -classpath "lib/wrapper.jar;conf;boot.jar" -Dwrapper.key="35GMYkROEBTyRT4O" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=2420 -Dwrapper.version="3.3.6" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.red5.server.Bootstrap
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | 
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Advice:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Usually when the Wrapper fails to start the JVM process, it is because
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | of a problem with the value of the configured Java command.  Currently:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | wrapper.java.command=java
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Please make sure that the PATH or any other referenced environment
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | variables are correctly defined for the current environment.
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | 
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 13:36:43 | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
```

Comment: btw: The label IIS is strange, I don't think that your issue is related to IIS. Maybe windows installer issues or something like that.

Comment: the logs actually tell us that java is not defined. If you open up a CMD and type "java" and hit enter, what happens?

Comment: seba.wagner: i tried - it displays some usage help, so i suppose it works .. :/

Comment: i just noticed somethign in the log:

STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/10/09 16:41:40 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.3.6

--> 32-bit .. as i'm running x64 i suppose i need to install the 32 bit version of java? o_O

Comment: Yes, the Java version you've installed should match the OS version. Either 32 or 64.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the red5.bat to get more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem as you and managed to resolve it I thought I'd share:

In my case I needed to add a reference to the bin-folder of the Java Runtime Environment under the PATH environment variable. `(Start --> Computer; Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> tab "advanced"; Environment Variables --> system variabeles; PATH variable.`

Click edit and add the path to the bin folder of your Java installation.